# How to solve react startup error "cannot find module 'which'"?

Tags: reactjs, startup

Hitting `npm start` in cmd in my project directory is giving the above error.

I tried `npm install -g which` but that did not work.

Screenshot of cmd

[image]

Screenshot of the complete error log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note:Please make a backup before applying these commmands.

These commands can help:

1)npm cache clean --force

2)remove/delete your node modules folder

3)npm install

4)npm start